# Cannot pass updated list in recursion function

Tags: python-3.x

I have a homework problem which requires me to check if a dictionary value is also a key word, and continue calling values until I find one that is not also a key. The trick is, you can get stuck on a never ending loop.

I tried to remedy this by tracking which values have previously been used in order to be able to kick out of recursion, but the homework problems auto grader does not allow this.

Here is my code:

```
def rabbit_hole(my_dict, string, new_list = []):
    if string in new_list:
        return False  
    try:
        new_list.append(string)
        value = my_dict[string]
        return rabbit_hole(my_dict, value, new_list)
    except:
        return string

d = {"bat": "pig", "pig": "cat", "cat": "dog", "dog": "ant",
     "cow": "bee", "bee": "elk", "elk": "fly", "ewe": "cod",
     "cod": "hen", "hog": "fox", "fox": "jay", "jay": "doe",
     "rat": "ram", "ram": "rat"}
```

In the example above, if we execute...

```
print(rabbit_hole(d, "rat"))
```

... this shows an example of a never ending loop and I would like it to return False. Is there an obvious reason this doesn't work with the auto grader? Or is there another way to track which keys have already been used?

Comment: It works for me

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your grader is checking for additional arguments to the function and doesn't allow for any.
How about just deleting the dictionary entry you've already checked?

```
def rabbit_hole(my_dict, string):
    try:
        value = my_dict[string]
        my_dict.pop(string, None)
        return rabbit_hole(my_dict, value)
    except:
        return string
```